# How to prevent click event in link or button using Vue directive

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Hi I'm playing around with vue directives and I'm trying to prevent click event if the element is `<a>` or `<button>` tag. So my question is, is this possible to do using vue directive?

**Html**

```
<a 
    @click.stop.prevent="displayModal()"
    v-noclick="test">
    I'm a link
</a>
```

**Vue directive**

```
Vue.directive('noclick', {
    bind( elem, binding, vnode ) {

        let user = {'name': 'John Doe'}

        if( user ) {
            let hasAccess = false

            if( !hasAccess ) {
                if( elem.tagName === 'A' ) {
                    elem.addEventListener( 'click', ( event ) => {
                        //this should prevent the element on click event
                        //but not working

                        event.stopPropagation()
                        event.preventDefault()
                        event.stopImmediatePropagation()
                        return false
                    })
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Vue registers the `@click` event first before `v-noclick` where you add a second click event listener on that element. When the `<a>` is clicked, the `displayModal()` function will be executed first, then the listener in the `v-noclick` directive will be executed. If the listeners were registered in the opposite order, then it would probably work.

That aside though, it doesn't look like what you are trying to do should be done inside a custom directive. Instead you can do the same logic in the click handler itself:

```vue
<a @click="onClick">Foo</a>
```

```es6
onClick() {
  if (whatever) {
    this.displayModal()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i couldn't find a vue way to do this. but with js you can use conditional sequence like this

```
<a @click="cond && onClick"></a>
```

in this case if cond be equals to true then onClick will called